# AutoMapper 10.0.0 with F# - How to fix it without additional mapping?

Tags: automapper

I have 3 types :

```
type [<CLIMutable>] status = { id : Guid; name : string }
type [<CLIMutable>] container = { id : Guid; name : string; status : status}
type [<CLIMutable>] scontainer = { id : Guid; name : string; status : string}
```

and next configuration

```
let c = 
        MapperConfiguration(
            fun config ->
                config.CreateMap<container, scontainer>()
                    .ForMemberFs((fun sc -> sc.name), (fun opts -> opts.MapFrom(fun m _ -> m.status.name))) |> ignore
        )
```

I'm trying to map with next code

```
let con = { id = Guid.NewGuid(); name = "Template 1"; container.status = { id = Guid.NewGuid(); name = "Draft" } }
let mapper = c.CreateMapper()
let sc = mapper.Map<scontainer>(con)
```

But member mapping isn't called and sc.status contains a string representation of status object(id and name together).

When I add new map:

```
config.CreateMap<status, string>().ConvertUsing(fun s -> s.name) |> ignore
```

then sc.status contains correct value.

Does anyone know how to make it work without additional mappings?

Comment: Apparently it's a F# thing. Check http://www.fssnip.net/c7/title/Using-AutoMapper-with-F.

Answer (score 0):

Next lines solves my problem:

```
let c = 
        AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(
            fun config ->
                config.ShouldMapProperty <- fun _ -> false
                config.ShouldMapField <- fun _ -> true
        )
```

Comment: Why is that? :)

Comment: Another workaround is to disable constructor using:
config.ShouldUseConstructor = ctor => false;
There is a very subtle bug when constructor is used. The bug appears when defined a constructor with the same parameters count and names as properties in the class. It is not related to F#, just F# helped fall into the corner case since F# compiler automatically generates constructor with the count and names matching fields defined in a record type.

Comment: All of this works in C#, so it must be about F# somehow. So it seems to me like you didn't really answered the question, you've just worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata produced for constructor is (id, name, status) in both scontainer and container.
Metadata produced for properties is: id, name, status in both scontainer and container.
Metadata produced for fields is: id@, name@, status@ in both scontainer and container.
If I don't disable properties usage then automapper will find a match between constructor parameters and properties and will use properties as resolver, which means constructor resolver will be used.
If I disable properties usage, then there will be no match between constructor parameters and fields and constructor will no be used.
I might be wrong but bug is in the next few lines in method: private void MapDestinationCtorToSource(TypeMap typeMap, List ctorParamConfigurations)
in next code:
var resolvers = new LinkedList();
var canResolve = typeMap.Profile.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(typeMap.SourceTypeDetails, destCtor.DeclaringType, parameter.GetType(), parameter.Name, resolvers, IsReverseMap);
if ((!canResolve && parameter.IsOptional) || IsConfigured(parameter))
{
canResolve = true;
}
Here is a test that reproduces a bug

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace ConstructorBug
{
    public class Status
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class SContainer
    {
        public SContainer()
        {
        }
        public SContainer(string id, string name, string status)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Status = status;
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }


    public class ConstructorBug
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ConstructorMapBug()
        {
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(
                    config =>
                    {
                        config.CreateMap<Container, SContainer>()
                            .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.Status.Name));
                    }
                );
            var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
            var con = new Container
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Container 1",
                Status = new Status { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Draft" }
            };
            var scon = mapper.Map<SContainer>(con);
            Assert.Equal(scon.Id, con.Id.ToString());
            Assert.Equal(scon.Name, con.Name);
            Assert.Equal(scon.Status, con.Status.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the desired behavior, `Status` was already mapped by construction, it will not be mapped again as property.

Comment: I find this behaviour a bit strange since there is no type matching between constructor parameter Status of type string and property Status of type which is not string.

Comment: Any type to string is a built in mapping. I'm not sure what fits better in your case. Perhaps tell AM what constructor you want used, maybe disable constructor mapping. I'm sure there are other ways, it depends. Also see [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: ForPath works well. It just overrides previously assigned value via constructor with a property setter.

Comment: `ForPath` is not for simple properties, and constructor mapping doesn't apply.